# Meaning of "хитровыебанный"

Tags: словоупотребление

What does it imply when someone describes or refers to another person as **хитровыебанный**? Is it a compliment or an insult? Also, what syllable is the stress on?

Comment: this word is actually VERY obscene, so look carefully around when saying. Not appropriate for any companies.
And I guess, the etymology may happen to be a phrase about "every sly nut" and "screw with non-standard thread", which got obscened to ass and dick instead, and next step perhaps was this neologism

Comment: and i'd expect this adjective used when the target person is thinking he is doing something canny and undecipherable, while in reality it is more that one is breaking the rules that others still abide too. It is not so much that others can not do the same, it is that the chose not to for some "greater good". Though of course like with any argot the borders are blurring with time and meaning overlapping grows.

Comment: I would disagree with "smart-ass" translation. "Xитровыебанный" has a much more negative connotation. I would suggest "weasel" is actually a closer translation.

Comment: I think `smart-ass` has a word-for-word translation: `хитрожопый`, applicable to humans and animals. `хитровыебанный` - a little different, much more rude, more abstract, applicable to animate and inanimate objects, situations, ways.

Comment: @Alexander Smart-ass also has a negative connotation

Comment: @CocoPop, yes of course it's not all black and white. But, across the usable range, "smart-ass" is  more positive than "weasel".

Comment: @Alexander What I meant is that smart-ass ONLY has a negative connotation. It's never a compliment.

Comment: @CocoPop I would not necessarily agree with that: [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smartass)

Comment: @Alexander I don't know where you're from, but as an American, I can assure you that calling someone a smart-ass is the same as calling them sarcastic, which is basically a slur in any context. Urban dictionary is fun, but not always accurate and reliable.

Comment: @CocoPop - I am not a native speaker, sorry, but sarcastic is not the same as derogatory. I know I can call an acquaintance "smart-ass" and we would have a chuckle, but if I call him "weasel", that would probably not be taken lightly.

Comment: @Alexander With the right intonation and attitude you can call an acquaintance anything in jest and it won't be taken wrong. What I mean is that smart-ass is never used to intimate that someone is intelligent or clever, which are positive traits. It always means "smart" in its negative sense of "sarcastic " regardless of whether you're serious or joking.

Comment: @CocoPop - I would agree that "smart-ass" probably never gets into a positive territory, but don't you think that "weasel" is more negative in comparison?

Comment: Weasel is in the same category in that it doesn't have any positive interpretation - it always means "slick" and "sneaky."  Smart-ass means "sarcastic" and "snide."

Comment: @CocoPop, if we are restricted to just 2 categories, then yes. However, I'm trying to find nuances within the same category. For example "cool", "cold" and "frigid" - do you see a gradation?

Comment: @Alexander That's a good question. I would say sassy - snippy - smart-ass - snide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's wrong to say that it's just obscene version of `хитрый` - it way more subtle.

`Хитровыебанный` is by no means `хитрый`. You cannot just say `хитровыебанный мужик` instead of `хитрый мужик` - this is just not right. You cannot substitute `хитрый` with `хитровыебанный` in the majority of cases - it's not just an obscene, rude form of sly or tricky.

It's closer (but not equivalent) to an obscene version of kludgy in the sense of "awkwardly or inelegantly made or done."

Let's take a look, for instance, at the phrase - `xитровыебанный план` - this refers to a plan that was actually cleverly or trickily conceived, but turns out to be overcomplicated and not necessarily effective.

**UPD:** As for `какой-то хитровыебанный хуй` - well, it's more like someone tried to say `какой-то хитрожопый хуй` (which is literally smart-ass) but was too worked up to calmly and thoroughly analyze all the possibilities in order to choose the right word.

Compare two google searches:

[image]
[image]

While you can use `хитровыебанный` to refer to a person (like `хитровыебанный пацан,` it's still not a direct analogue for `хитрый,` but rather for someone dodgy.

Comment: Thank you! But going back to my original question, what does this mean in relation to a person.? Actually, here's the original comment I saw this in: в данном конкретном примере я не концентрирвал внимание на пол стюардессы.  Меня лично тоже бесит, когда какой-нибудь хитровыебанный хуй в самолете начинает засовывать свои вещи в чужой отсек для багажа. Помню, пидор один мое место багажа занял, т.к. я чуть пожже в салон зашел. Нахрена мне это надо, разговаривать с каким-то мудаком ? Один раз , подобный чучело, тупо занял мое место у элюминатора и сидит смотрит своими тупыми глазами...

Comment: @CocoPop updated the answer trying to cover specifically your question.

Comment: @cocopop, see my 2nd comment to your 1. That is exactly the case of breaking co-inhabiting rules and being pride about allegedly being canny. The person in q occupied other's space without asking permission first and expecting that for the "greater good" of peaceful flight no one could challenge him. It is not that they really devised some smart-ass plan, it is that they exploiting others' wish to keep things peaceful and cooperative. By doing it they corrupt common environment/infrastructure in "tragedy of commons" way. So, this quite derogatory objective is used here,

Comment: @Arioch That is what we would call a douche-bag or a tool.

Comment: I have to mention that meaning of "хитровыебанный" is rather different when it applied to thing (like method of doing something) vs to a person. When applied to an inanimate thing, "хитровыебанный" can be translated as "weird, convoluted", and while it is obscene, it has no necessary negative connotation. "У него не было консервного ножа, и от открывал банки хитровыебанным способом." - "He had no can opener, so he've been opening cans in convoluted manner". However, when applied to a person, it has a strong negative connotation. It is still a synonym of "хитрый", but "less smart, more rude".

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, the word **хитровыебанный** has the same meaning as **хитрый** (cunning, tricky, sly), but obscene.

As pointed out by @DK in his comment, it can be translated as "smart-ass," but this word isn't only used to describe people; for instance, one can say "хитровыебанным способом," which means "in a tricky/clever way."

Comment: no, it is essentially brought down "sly" - the second part implies that the person thinks he is wicked smart while in reality he/she is damned scum

Comment: UPD, above I meant "intentionally brought down", not essentially

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation that occurs to me here is "sophisticated in a convoluted and bad manner", but in quite obscene language. The above-mentioned "Smart-ass" is probably the best short English translation, but it's much more derogatory in Russian. This is that famous brand of Russian cursing on an intermediate level.

An obligatory remark: this is not the kind of language that should be printed in books or spoken on any level beyond informal communication.

Answer (score 0):

**Хитровыебанный** is just `xитрый` (cunning, tricky, sly) - with a shade of admiration, as in *He's so cunning/smart - look at him!*

In a modern context: an American friend of mine used to say this about a former Russian Ambassador to US - [Kislyak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Kislyak) the same :)

Answer (score -2):

**Хитровыебанный** is a filty word and it does not have the same meaning as **хитрый.** **Хитровыебанный** means tricky and extremely complicated, more than it is required at the moment.

Comment: this answer does not add anything to the answers already provided